# lsb_release insists 18.04 is the latest LTS how do I get 20.04?

Tags: upgrade

I recently upgraded from 16.04 to 18.04 because the computer offered the upgrade. I didn't think anything of it until someone pointed out that 20.04 should be available.

I fear something is borked.

```
sudo do-release-upgrade -c
```

results in:

```
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
There is no development version of an LTS available.
To upgrade to the latest non-LTS development release 
set Prompt=normal in /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades.
```

but

```
lsb_release -a
```

results in:

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic
```

What should I do to resolve whatever issue my PC is having?

Comment: Be patient. That upgrade was coincidentally released about 24 hours ago, and not all mirrors have yet caught up.

Comment: FYI:  An upgrade from 16.04 LTS should only bump to the next release (16.10 but as it's EOL that's gone), or the next LTS which is 18.04. Your upgrade worked perfectly, it doesn't skip releases except from one LTS to **next** LTS.